# jRuby / Rails trying to find equivlent to php str_replace or urldecode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, urldecode

Not sure how to do this in Ruby/Rails only thing I could come up with is gsub. Which is giving me an undefined method.

What I am doing is via jQuery $.post is passing data to jRuby. My problem is, some browsers (most) are converting @ to %40, and , to %2C which is throwing a wrench in my works. So I want to catch specific ones to covert them to what they are supposed to be literally when "decoded".

I know this is a novice question, and I am almost positive the answer has to be on the web somewhere. But as I said I keep coming up on pages that suggest regex (which i want to avoid, and am not versed well with). Or others that suggest "gsub".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string is [URL encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Try to use [CGI::unescape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape):

```
require 'cgi'
CGI::unescape('%40') # => "@"
```